# Ubuntu 20.04 phpmyadmin not works

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 20.04.
http://localhost/phpmyadmin not works.

When I installed Ubuntu 20.04 i done this steps:

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt install apache2
3. sudo apt install mysql-server
4. sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
5. sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-zip php-gd php-json
   php-curl (password: password)
6. sudo apt install phpmyadmin
7. sudo mysql
8. INSTALL COMPONENT "file://component_validate_password";
9. sudo phpenmod mbstring
10. sudo systemctl restart apache2
11. ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password
    BY 'password';
12. mysql -u root -p
13. CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
    caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
14. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT
    OPTION;
15. sudo mysql_secure_installation (all i set No)

what am i missing ? what am i doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue. *It didn't install php*. Been using Ubuntu for something close to 2 decades and it's always automatically installed PHP as a dependency when installing phpmyadmin. Don't see how php isn't a dependency for phpmyadmin.  I'd file a bug but this is just stupid. It asks what server to use, and when you choose Apache it installs Apache 2 but *does not* install php or libapache2-mod-php.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a version issue. I installed phpmyadmin version 5, where PHP version was 7.4 which is not compatible with phpmyadmin version 5. After upgrading PHP version to 8.0 my issues went away. You can downgrade phpmyadmin or upgrade PHP or vice versa. In a word you should make sure that you are not making any version mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix the issue.

Usually, this is an issue after installation in 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04 (Focal Fossa) and higher too.

To fix it:

sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf

sudo systemctl restart apache2